# How do i change table zebra pattern colors using <input type='color'/>

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created two color picker to change table colors in html using input, but i don't know how to change those colors based off what user picks in color picker. I really, really don't want to use jquery and i prefer it to be really simple.
Also if it's needed you can find that site under: <www.kubera.cba.pl>

Comment: could you post the minimal html, css & js to replicate the issue, as well as the code you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a css variable and change the variable with JavaScript when the color is selected.

```js
const root = document.querySelector(':root');

function setColor (property, value) {
  root.style.setProperty(property, value);
}

document.querySelectorAll("[data-row]").forEach( function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener("input", function(){
    setColor(elem.dataset.row, elem.value);
  });
});
```

```css
:root {
  --odd: #CCCC33;
  --even: #EE33CC; 
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: var(--even);
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: var(--odd);
}
```

```html
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>5</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<label for="odd"><input type="color" id="odd" data-row="--odd" value="#CCCC33"/>

<label for="even"><input type="color" id="even" data-row="--even" value="#EE33CC" />
```

Comment: whoops, adjusted it. :)

Answer (score 0):

On your input color, put a change event where you can get the new color with "this.value".
Now apply the value to the element.

```
<input onchange="document.getElementById('yourTable').style.backgroundColor = this.value" type='color'/>
```

Comment: The main problem is that this will not allow you to style the zebra pattern, just the one universal background color, which is what this question was about. It works, but a solution with CSS variables is simple, clean and easier to understand.